# call parallelly function in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

i have an file serverlist  file,reading the file and getting the server name and performing  some operations on those servers using  for loop and command used:**/usr/local/bin/sshcmd -q -u $userName -s $serverName"** and one command for execution tooks 5-7 minutes on the one server.

i don't want to run the command one by  one on all servers but  requires to run the command at least 15 servers parallelly at same time for saving the time .

Answer (score 1):

You can run commands into background mode by adding '&' at end of command.
For example:
/usr/local/bin/sshcmd -q -u $userName1 -s $serverName1 &
/usr/local/bin/sshcmd -q -u $userName2 -s $serverName2 &

It is runs two copies of sshcmd parallely.

Comment: Thanks for response